# C++ OpenCV about scale and taking the value

Tags: c++, opencv

I wanna do some processings with an image. I used the resize function to do scaling (normalization).

```
std::string image_path = "test.png";
Mat image = imread(image_path, IMREAD_COLOR);
auto input_size = cv::Size(224, 224);
Mat resized;
cv::resize(image,resized,input_size,0,0,INTER_LINEAR);

cv::Mat Scaleimg;
resized.convertTo(Scaleimg, CV_32F, 1.0 / 255.0, 0);

Vec3b bgrPixel = Scaleimg.at<Vec3b>(100, 100);
std::cout << bgrPixel << endl << "--------------" << endl;
```

When I cout the resized this image on terminal, the values seem to be scaled.
For example:

0.35294119, 0.35294119, 0.35294119, 0.36470589, 0.36470589, 0.36470589, 0.35686275, 0.35686275, 0.35686275, 0.35294119, 0.35294119, 0.35294119, 0.36078432, 0.36078432, 0.36078432, 0.36078432, 0.36078432, 0.36078432, 0.36078432, 0.36078432, 0.36078432, 0.34117648, 0.34117648, 0.34117648, 0.32549021, 0.32549021, 0.32549021, 0.30980393, 0.30980393, 0.30980393, 0.27843139, 0.27843139, 0.27843139

However, when I took the value from this resized image to do further processing, the cout values seem not as same as the previous one.

The value of bgrPixel shows [145, 144, 144].

Doe anyone know how can I deal with this situation?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong `data type` for accessing a `3-Channel Float` pixel. The correct data type is [cv::Vec3f](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d84/group__core__basic.html#gab9e0ab642a3e01742916763173b72232), which is a `vector` of 3 float elements. This code snippet shows the modifications you need to perform:

```
// Scale Image:
cv::Mat Scaleimg;
resized.convertTo(Scaleimg, CV_32F, 1.0 / 255.0, 0);

// Loop thru image:
for( int i = 0; i < Scaleimg.rows; i++ ){
    for( int j = 0; j < Scaleimg.cols; j++ ){
        // Get float pixel:
        cv::Vec3f floatPixel = Scaleimg.at<cv::Vec3f>(i, j);
        // Print float pixel:
        std::cout<<"floatPixel( "<<i<<", "<<j<<"): "<<floatPixel<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @chiehpower Glad I could help, my friend!